# Different random weight initilization leading to different performances

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convergence, computer-vision

I'm training a 3D U-Net on an EM dataset of a brain. The objective is to segment neurons in it. During the experiments, I've noticed, different random initialization of the network leads to different performances. I evaluate the performance based on mean Intersection over Union, and I observe differences as large as 5%.

I use xavier initilization with a uniform distribution and use a constant learning rate of 1e-4.

Comment: Just want to confirm, do you use early stopping?

Comment: Yes, I'm using early stopping. I pick the model with the highest validation set accuracy and report its performance on the test set.

Comment: what's the question?